# Graphics and transformation in java

Tags: java

I begin to use java2d and I try to make rotation and translation of an image but a want to do this by a mouse event so I would like to know if there is any method to define a mouse event on an image added to `jframe` by  `g2d.drawImage(Image, Afftransform , this);`?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Have a read of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and once you have, edit the question so that there is a bit more information there and then we can begin to help you.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html